# MVC3 Razor - Formatting collection of strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a collection of strings that are repeated in MVC3 Razor with the following code:

```
        @if (Model.Publications != null)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>Publications</th>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var publication in @Model.Publications)
                    {
                        <text>@publication.Title</text>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Now when I display this, all I get is:

```
Book1Book2Book3
```

But I really want is something like this:

```
Book1, Book2, Book3
```

Is there a simple way in MVC razor to achieve this without having to combine 'if' and 'foreach' statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@string.Join(",",Model.Publications.Select(p=>"<text>"+ p.Title+ "</text>"))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string.Join(", ", model.Publications.Select(pub => pub.Title).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@if (Model.Publications != null)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>Publications</th>
                <td>
                    @var first = true
                    @foreach (var publication in @Model.Publications)
                    {
                        <text>@string.format("{0}{1}", first ? "" : ", ",  publication.Title)</text> 
                        @first = false;
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: This is one of the options but i myself like ans from Podiluska